# How to construct the DFA for the regular expression of a real number?

Tags: regex, automata, dfa

I'm trying to construct the Definite Finite Automata of a real number, that is defined as a string leading with an *optional* '+' or '-', followed by a single zero or non-empty sequence of digits that doesn't start with a zero. This is followed by a decimal point, which is followed by a non-empty sequence of digits.

I constructed the regular expression:
/[+ | -]?(O | ([1-9][0-9]*)).[0-9]+/

It can be tested on this site: http://rubular.com/

I'm really unsure on how to go about constructing a DFA, especially considering that there must be a defined state corresponding to each input on the transition table.

Answer (score 0):

This picture might be a solution

[image: DFA for the regex given]

Comment: I think that's NFA but OP is asking for DFA :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the DFA from the following website:
http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa

[image]